# How to handle django backend request for logged in user in a RESTfull manner?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I am developing a web platform that provides licence handling (e.g. creation, invoicing, downloading) for a specific software. Backend is django 2.1.7 and frontend angular.

I have the following use case and I want to make sure it respects REST architecture and that it is future proof (avoid pitfalls).

So I have 2 apis:

- ip/userprofiles
- ip/licences

These 2 apis are protected and can be accessed only after log in.

In my current implementation the GET requests for these 2 api's return only data specific to the logged in user by extracting the user id and name from the request.user (so for the authenticated user) information.

```
User with user1 name logged in (NOT admin).
GET ip/userprofiles will return user1 profile.
GET ip/licences will return user1 licences.
```

Another use case would be that the admin should have access to all licences and all users and for this I do a check to see if the request.user is admin.

```
User with user10 name logged in (user10 IS admin):
GET ip/userprofiles will return ALL users profiles.
GET ip/licences will return ALL licences (for all user).
```

For admin users the apis allows also filtering by users using a query string parameter.

Is this approach ok from REST point of view and also from security point of view? Any pitfalls I should watch out for?

Should I be using also for non admin users the same approach as for admin users as in to specify the current user id as a query string parameter in the frontend and not extract the user in the backend from request.user (authenticated user information)? 
This solution does not seem secure to me but might be a limitation for the future (although currently I don't see any use case in which a user should have access to other users licences and profiles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I don't agree with what you're pitching. Each API endpoint should have one responsibility per request action. A GET request at `ip/userprofiles` should either always return a single object or a list of objects. This simplifies the client's logic so that it can translate the result consistently.

Here's what I'd suggestion:

```
# Detail / Single Object Endpoints:
ip/userprofile
ip/license
```

These two always return the current users profile and license respectively regardless of admin status.

```
# List Endpoints
ip/userprofiles
ip/licenses
```

These two always return a list of users and licenses respectively, but would have some validation (in DRF a permission class) that would only return data if `request.user` is an admin. If a user isn't an admin, it'd return a 403 error.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your answer. I understand your point of view and seems like a more consistent way of handling my issue.